# differential equations solve for exponents

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x' = A(t)x$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $A$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

$$A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1+\sin(t)&0&0\\ 0&3&4\\ 0&1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

The question is to find the Floquet exponents and it also asked to find Lyapunov exponents. I am kind of new to ordinary differential equations, and it would be very nice to show step by steps to solve this problem to firmly understand the concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original system consists of 2 parts:
$$\tag{1}
\dot x=(1+\sin t)x
$$
and
$$\tag{2}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{array}{c}y\\z\end{array}\right)=
B\left(\begin{array}{c}y\\z\end{array}\right),\qquad B=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
3&4\\1&3
\end{array}\right).
$$
We can solve them separately, obtaining
$$
x(t)=C_1e^{t-\cos t}
$$
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}y\\z\end{array}\right)=
e^{Bt}\left(\begin{array}{c}C_2\\C_3\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{5t}/2 + e^t/2&     e^{5t} - e^t\\
 e^{5t}/4 - e^t/4& e^{5t}/2 + e^t/2
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}C_2\\C_3\end{array}\right);
$$
or
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{t-\cos t}&0&0\\
0& e^{5t}/2 + e^t/2&     e^{5t} - e^t\\
0& e^{5t}/4 - e^t/4& e^{5t}/2 + e^t/2
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}C_1\\C_2\\C_3\end{array}\right)=X(t)
\left(\begin{array}{c}C_1\\C_2\\C_3\end{array}\right).
$$
The fundamental matrix $X(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
e^{t-\cos t}&0\\ \hline
0&e^{Bt}
\end{array}\right)$ can be written in the Floquet's canonical form 
$$
X(t)=\Phi(t)e^{\Lambda t},
$$
where
$$
\Phi(t)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{-\cos t}&0&0\\
0& 1&     0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
is a $2\pi$ periodic matrix,
$$
e^{\Lambda t}=
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
e^t&0\\ \hline
0&e^{Bt}
\end{array}\right)=
e^{
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
t&0\\ \hline
0&Bt
\end{array}\right)}=
e^{
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
1&0\\ \hline
0&B
\end{array}\right)t},
$$
hence,
$$
\Lambda=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0& 3&  4\\
0& 1& 3
\end{array}\right).
$$
$\Lambda$ has the eigenvalues  $1,1,5$, thus,
the Floquet multipliers of the system are the eigenvalues of 
$e^{2\pi\Lambda}$, i.e. $e^{2\pi}$, $e^{2\pi}$, $e^{10\pi}$;
the Floquet exponents are $1,1,5$; The Lyapunov exponents are the real parts of the Floquet exponents, so they are equal to $1,1,5$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! Just got an one more question if possible, what if the A matrix is [-1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1+sin(t); 0, -1-sin(t), 0]? Thank you for your help again.

Comment: @James333 This system again consists of 2 systems: $\dot x=-x$ and the linear system with $B(t)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0& 1+\sin(t)\\ -1-\sin(t)& 0 \end{array}\right)$. The matrix $B(t)$ has the property: $\forall t,s\in\mathbb R$ $A(t)A(s)=A(s)A(t)$. It implies that the fundamental matrix of the second system is $$e^{\int_0^t B(\tau)\,d\tau}=e^{\left(\begin{array}{cc}0& t-\cos(t)\\ -t+\cos(t)& 0 \end{array}\right)}=e^{\left(\begin{array}{cc}0& -\cos(t)\\ \cos(t)& 0 \end{array}\right)}e^{\left(\begin{array}{cc}0& 1\\ -1& 0 \end{array}\right)t}$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that $B(t)B(s)=B(s)B(t)$

Comment: Thank you again for the comment! So, the Λ matrix will now have [1, 0, 0; 0, 0, t; 0, -t, 0], Then, how would you calculate for the eigenvalues if it has t in the matrix to get the Floquet multipliers.

Comment: @James333 No, $\Lambda$ is a constant matrix; in this case, $\Lambda=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}-1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Then, the eigenvalues are -1, i, -i. So, the Floquet exponents are -1, i, -i and the Lyapunov exponents are real part so it would be just -1, right?

Comment: @James333 -1,0,0

Comment: @AVK Just came across your very nice comments. Do you know whether we can find the Floquet exponents for the more general case of $\pmb{x}'\left(t\right) = \pmb{B}\left(t\right)\pmb{x}\left(t\right)$ (i.e., when $\pmb{B}(t)\pmb{B}(s) \neq \pmb{B}(s)\pmb{B}(t)$)? I am most interested in the $2\times 2$ case. My more detailed question is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914856/finding-the-characteristic-exponents-floquet-lyapunov-exponents-of-odes-with-p